# CSS Vertical dropdown menu, When Hover to other menu the submenu shows

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

What is the proper or best way to do this? I can't fix it :3
The submenu of members shows when you hover to the other menus
What's the problem with my code? I can't figure it out :3
you can see my codes in the link

`http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaxmvO`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="logo"><a href="#">WORKOUT <span>FITNESS CENTER</span></a></div>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Walk-In</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List of Members</a>
                        <li><a href="#">Subscr</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Suppliers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="content">
            SOME CONTENT YAY
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300italic,300);
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #858585;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: 15px;  
}

.logo a{
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #070807;

}
.logo a span{
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #1AC93A;
}

nav{
    width: 250px;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: #171717;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    width: :auto;
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    padding: 15px
}

nav li{
    list-style: none;

}

nav li a{
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

nav li a:hover{
    background-color: #030303;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 80px;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You need like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwBdMe

Comment: Thanks! with just ">" I'm ruined hahah I think I need to learn how to use that hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaEWJw

**HTML**

```
 <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Walk-In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List of Members</a>             
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Subscr</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Suppliers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover  ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the specific element and then show the sub menu. I added an `id` to this `li` to make it easier to target and got rid of the `</li>` so the `ul` is inside `li#members`.

```
<li id="members"><a href="#">Members</a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">List of Members</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Subscr</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">asdasd</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

nav #members:hover ul{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaxmvO) what's the problem with this? I think it's correct but, the submenu doesn't show when hover

Comment: `<li id="members"><a href="#">Members</a></li>` you need to get rid of `</li>` then it should work